# make mui multiple ddl search able and get id's from multiple values for form submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the recommended approach for creating a dropdown searchable with multiple selection functionality, where the selected text's should be displayed in ddl and the values i want submit through form the value i mean id's?

I am looking for guidance on how to implement a dropdown component that allows multiple selections and also shows the selected values and should be search able in the dropdown itself. Currently, I am using a <Select> component from Material-UI library with the multiple prop. The selected values are stored in the roleid state variable, and I am using the handleChangeUserRole function to handle the selection changes. However, I would like to enhance the functionality so that the selected values are displayed in the dropdown alongside their corresponding text.

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions for implementation of searching on the best practices or alternative solutions for achieving this requirement. Thank you in advance!

this is my code

```
// My state
  const [roleid, setRoleId] = useState<any>([]);
//Change Function 
 const handleChangeUserRole = (event: SelectChangeEvent<string[]>) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
  
    setRoleId(typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    
  };

// this is my drop down code 

 <FormControl>
         <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">
            {translate('User.userRoles')}
         </InputLabel>
         <Select
           labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
           id="demo-multiple-name"
           name="userRoles"
           multiple
           value={roleid}
           onChange={handleChangeUserRole}
           input={<OutlinedInput label={translate('User.userRoles')} />}
           MenuProps={MenuProps}
           >
           {RolesOption.map((role) => (
             <MenuItem
               key={role.value}
               value={role.value}
               // style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}                    >
               {role.text}
               </MenuItem>
                ))}
        </Select>
</FormControl>
```